# Cannot replicate Chrome request with cURL

Tags: google-chrome, curl, authentication

I want to use Python's `requests` module to login to the webpage https://www.tennistv.com/login. With Chrome's developer tools I looked up how the request looks that is sent after the login button is hit.

A POST request to the URL `https://www.tennistv.com/api/users/v1/login` is generated with JSON payload in the form of `{"Email":"[MAIL]","Password":"[PASSWORD]"}`. However I can't get it to work neither with Python's requests module nor with cURL. Chrome's Developer tools have the option to generate a cURL command with a request. And that's what I did, but even the cURL request yields the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "validationErrors": [{
            "key": "loginModel",
            "value": [""]
        }],
        "errorMessage": "There was an error while validating input data (UR001)",
        "errorCode": "UR001",
        "userErrorCode": "UR001"
    }
}
```

The generated cURL request looks as follows:

`curl "https://www.tennistv.com/api/users/v1/login" -H "Pragma: no-cache" -H "Origin: https://www.tennistv.com" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -H "Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36" -H "content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Referer: https://www.tennistv.com/login" -H "Connection: keep-alive" --data-binary "^{^\^"Email^\^":^\^"[MAIL]^\^",^\^"Password^\^":^\^"[PASS]^\^"^}" --compressed`

The request by Chrome looks like this:

[image]

How can I get the cURL request to work? What is the difference between the request sent by Chrome and cURL?

Answer (score 0):

Try this cURL :

```
curl -v "https://www.tennistv.com/api/users/v1/login" \
-H "Pragma: no-cache" \
-H "Origin: https://www.tennistv.com" \
-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" \
-H "Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7" \
-H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-H "Accept: */*" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-H "Referer: https://www.tennistv.com/login" \
-H "Connection: keep-alive" \
--data-binary '{"Email":"foobar@domain.tld","Password":"xxx"}'
```

(edit the last line with your credentials)